# Is there an alternative to the iframe that will resize to dynamic content?

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

Considering that iframes do not resize to dynamic content, can anyone suggest something else that I can use? I need something that will resize like a table and can be used for dynamic content.

The ideal suggestion would provide all of the functionality of iframes, plus resizing. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to include proper use of upper-case letters, actual words and whole sentences, in a way suitable for mature people. Next, are you loading pages from another domain?

Comment: If your iframe content is loaded form the same domain as the parent frame you can use javascript to obtain the size of the content, and resize the iframe accordingly.

Comment: @Kobi: Agree. It's fixed now.

Comment: no same domain, a page from my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try jQuery with Fancybox or Colorbox plugin. I know that they resize images, but I haven't tested with html content. But both have a method called .resize for auto resizing content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ajax call to load the content and insert it into your current page via eg. jQuery.

Of course, getting any interaction with the content to work like planned could be an obstacle. Specially if the content is from another site.